# How to refer javascript file in html present in another folder

Tags: javascript, html, web

I have a JS file in folder
/admintool/src/main/webapp/static/js/itemInventory.js

i have html file in folder
/admintool/src/main/webapp/WEB-INF/templates/itemInventory.ms

On page load my starts with url - http://localhost:8080/admintool/selectItem/showAllItems

Inside itemInventory.ms file, when i use the below code to refer that javascript, it is not able to detect it.

```
<script src="static/js/itemInventory.js"></script>
```

In browser console, i get an error 
GET http://localhost:8080/admintool/selectItem/static/js/itemInventory.js net::ERR_ABORTED

How do i specify the location of this JS file properly ?

Answer (score 0):

Are you sure, that the links are right? The link from the HTML to the JavaScript have to be:
../../static/js/itemInventory.js

Ivo